# NodeJS: using chrome-remote-interface instead puppeteer

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer, npm-scripts

I have a project which uses puppeteer to print PDFs, the problem is the download of chromium is too large to work with servers, so I want to migrate it to chrome-remote-interface instead. There is a better way to do that? I will change too much my code?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to switch to such libraries for this problem. Puppeteer already has solution for that.

## puppeteer-core

Puppeteer has `puppeteer-core` library which is without the chrome download and will work with remote interface.

The only difference between puppeteer-core and puppeteer atm is that puppeteer-core doesn't install chromium. So you can just swipe it.

The original difference is [described here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteer-vs-puppeteer-core). The document for `.connect` is [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerconnectoptions).

## Using the environment variable

You can use puppeteer as usual, except provide  `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD` environment variable to skip the download when doing `npm install`.